# Logging on mpi4py child files

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, mpi

I am using `mpi4py` to distribute work to different files. Does anyone know how I can include logging information of these child processes into my log-file. I call my child processes in the following way:

```
comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable,
                           args=['child.py'],
                           maxprocs = procs)
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been discussed in the mpi4py google groups before. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mpi4py/SaNzc8bdj6U for some specific information about how to allow each child to log to a file.

HTH